# whats are the pros and cons of nullable constructor and methods with variables

Tags: java

This is probably a very basic question but at the moment i'm practicing with spring and notice that the `@autowire` annotation creates a constructor without variables in the background and forces to use methods.

So now i have following question what is the difference between.

```
public class Example {

    private String stuffA;

    private String moreStuffB;

    private User user ;


    public Example(String stuffA, String moreStuffB, User user) {
        this.stuffA = stuffA;
        this.moreStuffB = moreStuffB;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String ShowUserName (){

        return user.getFirstName();

    }

    public String ShowStuff(){

        return stuffA + " " + moreStuffB;

    }

}
```

And this :

```
public class Example {



    public Example() {
    }

    public String ShowUserName (User user){

        return user.getFirstName();

    }

    public String ShowStuff(String stuffA,String moreStuffB){

        return stuffA + " " + moreStuffB;

    }

}
```

What is the preferred way or does it depends on the situation? 
And what are the pro's and con's between these 2 examples?

Comment: The default constructor is redundant in the second snippet, and doesn't exist in the first one.

Comment: why would you go for instance variable? what's the relationship between string and that example class i.e. HAS-A or USES?

Comment: But is there a preferred way because in this situation they are different but  gives the same result. And when should you use A or B.

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "null constructor" and "methods with all the variables"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you call  `example.showStuff()`.

In the second case, you call `example.showStuff("stuff", "moreStuff")`.

The difference is whether the caller needs to be able to provide the values for these two objects or they are part of the object instance.

Real-life example for a combination of both:

```
dateFormatter.format(yesterday)
```

Here the caller provides the date to format, but the dateFormatter knows what formatting pattern should be used.